# Pandas list comparison giving value error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, debugging

I have a dataframe I generate by using

```
df = qr_actions.get_pandas_df(query)
```

and then generate a list of the rows using `rows = [r[1] for r in df.iterrows()]` and am trying to compare it to another list of rows I generate using the same method by doing `(rows1 == rows2).all()`, but keep getting the error

```
Name: 0, dtype: bool

    def __nonzero__(self):
        raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
                         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
>                        .format(self.__class__.__name__))
E       ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:892: ValueError
```

How can I do this? When I try to use pandas series equality functions I get errors because my objects are lists, but doing rows1 == rows2 alone gives me the output above. How can I solve this?

===================================================

Alternatively, I know my two rows are both

```
[a    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64]
```

How can I compare them to assert true for testing purposes?

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example, what is the content of `df`? what is `rows2`? What is the ultimate goal? You should be able not to use a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Your `rows` is a list and a operation `rows1 == rows2` will return a boolean after which you can't apply `all` attribute. Converting your rows to `pd.Series` will solve the issue:

```
rows = pd.Series([r[1] for r in dftest.iterrows()])
```

Comment: I would like to keep them as lists but using ``==`` without the ``all`` still gives me the exception above. Why is this?

Comment: I don't know how your actual dataframe looks like. It doesn't raise an error for a sample dataframe I run.